# Collapsed ContentPanel doesn't show new Heading

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a ContentPanel, that is set to collapsable

```
ContentPanel bottomPanel = new ContentPanel();
BorderLayoutData layoutData = new BorderLayoutData(LayoutRegion.SOUTH);
layoutData.setSplit(true);
layoutData.setCollapsible(true);

// some code

add(bottomPanel, layoutData);
```

and set the heading of that panel with

```
bottomPanel.setHeading("title");
```

If the panel is not collapsed, setting the heading sets a new heading of that panel. But if the panel is collapsed it doesn't work. The heading always shows the last heading set while not collapsed.
In both states, the collapsed and the not collapsed, the getter always returns the new heading

```
bottomPanel.getHeading(); // "old Heading"
bottomPanel.setHeading("new Heading");
bottomPanel.getHeading(); // "new Heading"
```

I think it is kind of render problem

Comment: call bottomPanel.layout() after setting new heading

Comment: neither calling bottomPanel.layout() nor bottomPanel.repaint() work

Comment: Once heading is set to the gxt contentpanel ,Either it is Collapsed or not Collapsed it will be there.So after collapsing u must set header and call layout.

Comment: The problem is not, that the heading isn't shown after collapsing. After collapsing it shows the heading from before. But if it is collapsed and I call setHeading it doesn't show the new heading. In other words, if it is collapsed and I call setHeading and layout it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a ContentPanel is collapsed, the titlebar (HEAD) is replaced by a CollapsedPanel, which creates its own header element and it is not accesible for modification (even if you change the ContentPanel heading).

Check the CollapsePanel.class > onRender(...)

```
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.ContentPanel
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.CollapsePanel
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.BorderLayout
```

Comment: So there is no way to set the heading if the panel is collapsed?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the time, not by using the control as it is.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to update the heading of a ContentPanel while it is collapsed one can code a workaround:

1. expand the panel
2. set a new heading
3. collapse the panel

Besides that this is a workaround and not beautiful there is only one drawback to it: the user will see the panel collapsing (automatically). As long as this won't bother you this workaround will set a new heading to a "collapsed" panel.

First of all: don't call `setCollapsible(boolean)` on the `LayoutData`, but on the `ContentPanel`! Otherwise this won't work.

```
ContentPanel bottomPanel = new ContentPanel();
bottomPanel.setCollapsible(true);
BorderLayoutData layoutData = new BorderLayoutData(LayoutRegion.SOUTH);
layoutData.setSplit(true);
//layoutData.setCollapsible(true);
```

After this is done you may set the new heading like this:

```
public void setNewHeading(ContentPanel panel, String heading) {
  if(panel.isCollapsed()) {
    panel.expand();
  }

  panel.setHeading(heading);

  DeferredCommand.addCommand(new Command() {
    public void execute() {
      panel.collapse();
    }
  });
}
```

The key here is the `DeferredCommand`, which will execute when all currently pending event handlers have completed.

Answer (score 0):

here's a simplified version of what I use to do (GXT 3).

The code below displays some text in the CollapsePanel when the north widget is collapsed:

```
borderLayoutContainer.addCollapseHandler(
    new CollapseItemHandler<ContentPanel>() {
        @Override
        public void onCollapse(CollapseItemEvent<ContentPanel> event) {
            if (event.getItem() == northContentPanel) {
                CollapsePanel collapsePanel = (CollapsePanel) borderLayoutContainer.getNorthWidget();
                collapsePanel.getElement().insertFirst("<span style='color: red; font-size: bold;'>Here is the collapsed panel title</span>");
            }
        }
    });
```

Of course that instead of inserting your title as the first element of the CollapsePanel you could do something smarter like [inserting a complex widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183181/how-to-add-a-custom-widget-to-an-element).