# attach a gwt widget to an element

Tags: gwt

I am trying to attach a widget in GWT to an element.  I see this example, 
[How to add a custom widget to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183181/how-to-add-a-custom-widget-to-an-element/6186394#6186394)

but when I use HTMLPanel.wrap() I get an UmbrellaException.  Exception is happening on this line:
assert Document.get().getBody().isOrHasChild(element);

How do I get my element to be attached to the DOM?  Below is the code I am using:

```
@UiField
TableElement tblBootstrap;

public void addRow() {
  TableRowElement row = tblBootstrap.insertRow(-1);
  TableCellElement c = row.insertCell(-1);
  HTMLPanel.wrap(c).add(new TextBox());
}
```

Many Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Add your exception log. UmbrellaException is just a wrapper, the real cause/exception is further down.

Comment: Did you init your UIBinder? If the @UIField is not initialized yet, it may cause the exception. (But you should add the Stacktrace)

Comment: Uncaught com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: 
Exception caught: undefinedSimpleEventBus.java:203 
doFire_0_g$SimpleEventBus.java:88 
fireEvent_2_g$PlaceController.java:156 
goTo_0_g$PlaceHistoryHandler.java:192 
handleHistoryToken_0_g$PlaceHistoryHandler.java:118 
handleCurrentHistory_0_g$App.java:23 
onModuleLoad_4_g$com_00046pinetreetechnology_00046App__EntryMethodHolder.java:3 
init_3_g$ModuleUtils.java:44 
initializeModules_0_g$Impl.java:247 
apply_0_g$Impl.java:306 
entry0_0_g$Impl.java:72 
(anonymous function)ModuleUtils.java:55 
gwtOnLoad_0_g$ListIterator.java:28

Comment: from what I understand to use HTMLPanel.wrap(), your element has to be on the DOM before you attempt to wrap it.  when I call

    TableCellElement cell = row.insertCell(-1);

is cell instantly placed on the DOM so I can wrap it?